# extract a word from a passage based on placement of the word

Tags: c#

Suppose i have a passage of text(note this is made up and my sample has a lot more text):

"Hello

This is my password: abc123

goodbye"

I know the password is going to be imediately after the sentence "This is my password: "

Also that the password will be 8 chars.
How can i extract the password above?

Comment: I don't clearly understand your question..

Comment: @SonerGönül, so i have a string as above from which i'm trying to extract the password

Comment: Funny you said the password is 8 characters and gave a 6 character password in the example.

Answer (score 0):

```
    string Password = Regex.Replace(Input, @"^.*This is my password: (.{8}).*$", "$1", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know Regex:

```
string data = "Hello.\n This is my password: abcd1234 n\goodbye.";
string passFlag = "This is my password: ";
int startPos = data.IndexOf(passFlag) + passFlag.Length;
string password;
if(startPos >= 0 )
    password = data.Substring(startPos,startPos+8);
```

Comment: case sensitive search?  Adding data.Length to the startPos?  Not checking whether the search string was found?

Comment: Well he said he knew what came before the password so case shouldn't matter. Good points otherwise.